# Limit user to fill a Infopath list

Tags: 2013, infopath, user

I have create a list in Infopath and published it in SharePoint. I want to limit users to fill in this list just once.

How can I do this?

I have Nintex if it's necessary to write a workflow.

Comment: One way would be to create a workflow that remove the users permission from the list when they created a list item.

Comment: nintex has a action named "set item permission",Do I must to use this? and if the answer is yes can you explain the setting for this Purpose. thanks for your attention

Answer (score 1):

1. Initially create 2 SharePoint groups one with Contribute permissions and another with read. Put all the users to group with Contribute permissions. Once a user fill the form, remove the user from that group and add to the group with Read permissions.
2. Assign required users individually Contribute permissions. When submitted, remove permissions and apply Read permissions.

This permissions can be set using a Nintex workflow as it is easy with Nintex.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a browser based form which does not give the user access to the toolbars (Save, Submit, etc.):

I would create a secondary data connection to the library that the forms are saved in.

Then I would retrieve the Created By column values.

I would check that list for the current user, using a rule on form open.

If the current user is in that list, then the view should switch on form open to one that says "You have already filled this form in" (or similar) with just an exit button.